# Pro Android 2: What does system.out.println in Android?

Tags: android

To the best of my (current) understanding, Android has no console to send the messages to so the System.out.println messages get lost. Instead, Log.x (outputing to LogCat) should be used.

Yet, in the acclaimed Pro Android 2 book, [listing 8-1](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4529) does just that:

```
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
    }
    in.close();

    String page = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(page);
```

Does **System.out.println** really work in Android or is it only a typo?

If the former (i.e. *not* a typo), what does it really do and where should I expect to find the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout):

> By default, the Android system sends stdout and stderr (System.out and System.err) output to /dev/null.

It also explains how to use System.out and System.err properly.

Comment: It actually does work (by default without any modifications to the settings). See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

System.out.println prints to whatever is currently defined as the "standard" output PrintStream.  It is possible to hook this up to point to the log stream, but really there is no good reason to use it.  Use Log.x.

This is probably just a typo in the book.  Nothing in that code snippet is Android specific.

Comment: Yeah, I'd vote for "code copied from a normal Java book with minimal adjustments to make it work on Android."

Comment: @EboMike The aforementioned book *is* an Android book. :)  @Mayra Thanks.

Comment: @Android: Yes, it is, but the author probably got that piece of code from somewhere else and adjusted it for Android. We have 16 years worth of Java code fragments flying around in the world, I'm sure there was something that could be used. That, or the others are Java experts but relatively new to Android.

Comment: @EboMike I wish this was the only typo in that book... :(

Comment: Go for Mark's books. At least he knows what he's talking about.

Comment: As I noted in my other comment below, the documentation in the DevGuide is wrong regarding what println does. Chapter 2 of Pro Android 2 specifically says you should use Log.x and not rely on println to function properly. The code in chapter 8 was lifted from a non-Android project, but it does work. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

That System.out.println code does work (despite what the android documentation says). I've tried it on my on my Android development set up (without changing the settings as they describe in the documentation). I've had tried on the set ups of my Android programming students, both on their Windows and Macs. And it always comes out the same way:

The following line does output to logcat by default.

> System.out.println("blah blah");

Now of course, it's probably best to stick to Log.x() anyway. It's probably never a good idea to rely on undocumented features, especially in a book. This feature could be here today, and be just as well gone the next time the tools get updated.

Comment: The docs (as referenced above) are wrong. It's not uncommon to find documentation errors. Check out this bug report that says the default behavior got changed: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=92

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, System.out will be displayed on the LogCat tab not in the Console.
You can also try the Log.i("MyLog", "The message here...."); also displayed on the LogCat.

Enjoy!